# DatastoreJDOPersistenceManagerFactory class not found exception when configuring JDO on Appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo, google-plugin-eclipse

I am trying to configure JDO on Appengine but every time I try to persist something I get an 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOPersistenceManagerFactory
Searching for this error I only got that I could have an error in my jdoconfig.xml
But I explicitly declare that I want to use this class my jdoconfig.xml, which I posted below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jdoconfig xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig">
  <persistence-manager-factory name="transactions-optional">
    <property name="javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass"
            value="org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOPersistenceManagerFactory"/>
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.RetainValues" value="true"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns" value="true"/>
  </persistence-manager-factory>
</jdoconfig>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

decide if you are using GAE JDO plugin v1.0 (JDO2.x) or GAE JDO plugin v2.0 (JDO3.0) which kinda decides which jars you have in the classpath, and hence what entries you put in your *jdoconfig.xml*